# flutter Getx update ui in from textspan recognizer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

i want to update the UI when double tap on textspan but i unable to achieve this the UI not updating when press and i tried using Obx but  the same.
Help :)

**And this is the code of the RichText**

```
class QuranTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<QuranPage> quranV2;
  final QuranPageController controller;
  const QuranTextWidget(this.quranV2, this.controller, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final lines = List.generate(15, (_) => <InlineSpan>[]);

    void buildLines(QuranPage verse, Words word, List<InlineSpan> list) {
      list.add(TextSpan(
        recognizer: DoubleTapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onDoubleTap = () {
            verse.isSelected.value = true;
            controller.update();
          },
        text: word.codeV1,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'UthmanTN3',
          color: word.charTypeName == 'end'
              ? Color.fromARGB(255, 147, 189, 211)
              : Colors.grey.shade100,
          backgroundColor: verse.isSelected.value
              ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 147, 189, 211)
              : Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ));
    }

    for (var verse in quranV2) {
      for (var word in verse.words!) {
        final lineNumber = word.lineNumber! - 1;
        if (lineNumber >= 0 && lineNumber < lines.length) {
          buildLines(verse, word, lines[lineNumber]);
        }
      }
    }

    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        final textWidget = GetBuilder<PrayerTimesController>(
          builder: (controller) {
            return RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  for (var line in lines) ...[
                    TextSpan(children: line),
                    if (line != lines.last) const TextSpan(text: '\n'),
                  ],
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        );

        return orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? PortraitLayout(textWidget)
            : LandscapeLayout(textWidget);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

i tried a lot of ways but only one works and its really long

to loop over every line inside the rich text thats mean i have to repeat the code 15 times
please help me i spend 2 days work on this and i fail.